# Show that $(\Bbb Z, +)$ and $(\Bbb R, +)$ are not isomorphic groups .

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, epimorphisms

Show that $(\Bbb Z, +)$ and $(\Bbb R, +)$ are not isomorphic groups.

What I did so far:

> To show that these groups are not isomorphic, we need first assume that, there exists an isomorphism $f$ from $(\Bbb Z, +)$ onto $(\Bbb R, +)$. Then,$f(a^n)=f(\underbrace {a.a...a}_{\text{n times}})$(,where $.$ is an arbitary binary operation. But $+$ is the binary operation given, so $f(1^n)=f(\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{\text{n times}})=f(n)=\underbrace {f(1)+\cdots+f(1)}_{\text{n times}}=nf(1)$. Thus, we have, $f(n)=nf(1)$. So, $f$ is completely known if $f(1)$ is known. If $f(1)=r\in\Bbb R$, then, $\forall x\in\Bbb R$,$\exists n\in \Bbb Z$, such that, $f(n)=rn=x$.

But I dont know how to arrive at a contradiction from here. My general strategies include : trying to show that if one group has an element of a **particular order** then the other group does not have a corresponding element of that **particular order**, showing that we can't find a pre-image of the "image" group. But I don’t know what to do here? Also, I am still learning *elementary group theory* and I need an "elementary" solution  for the same(, without using **cardinality of sets**, as I still don'tknow about countability,uncountablity and other related topics).

Although , the following thread [Is $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731971/is-mathbbz-isomorphic-to-mathbbr) is about this same topic, but the answers there weren't suitable for me, because I couldn't understand the 1st answer , furthermore, it addresses a specific doubt of the user (if I am not mistaken). As for the 2nd answer, I am not quite fond of it . Actually,I was looking for the particular type of answer provided in the *comments* by lulu.

Comment: Let $g$ be the isomorphism from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb Z$.  If $g(x)=1$ then $2\times g\left(\frac x2\right)=1$.

Comment: @lulu So to complete your argument, if we take an isomorphism $f$ from $\Bbb R$ onto $\Bbb Z$, then $\exists x\in \Bbb R$, such that $f(x)=1$, then, $$f(x/2+x/2)=1=f(x/2)+f(x/2)=2f(x/2)$$ since, $x/2\in\Bbb R$, thus $f(x/2)=1/2$ , contradiction as $1/2\notin \Bbb{Z}$. So, $f$ is not a homomorphism, and hence, $f$ is not an isomorphism as well. Thus, no such isomorphism exists and hence, $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb R$ are not isomorphic. Is this a correct solution ?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to say "there is no integer $n$ such that $2n=1$".

Comment: @lulu That's a good argument too! But ,nevertheless will my solution in my previous comment hold valid ?...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that $g\left( \frac x2\right)=\frac 12$ since $\frac 12$ isn't an integer.  As a result, $g\left( \frac x2\right)$ is undefined, hence $g$ isn't even a function.

Comment: Note:  the same argument shows that the additive groups $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$ are not isomorphic...and in that case, cardinality arguments would not help (both sets are countable).

Comment: @lulu  But that's the whole point of the argument ? I considered $f$ to be an isomorphism after which , I arrived at the fact that, $f$ **cannot be a function** . This proves that, we can't even consider an isomorphism between two groups . If the two groups were isomorphic the function $f$ considered would've been defined everywhere in the domain i.e $\Bbb R$(here).Due to which , they are not isomorphic. Your  argument is the same  (if I am not wrong?) but just phrased differently, isn't it?

Comment: Try it this way:. Assuming $g$  exists, then $g(x/2)=m$ for some integer $m$.  Then we get $2m=1$, an impossibility so $g$ can not exist.

Comment: @lulu Yeah! If we phrase the argument just like you said, it becomes better. The way arguments are written in mathematics (seems  minute , though) but makes such a big difference to comprehend ,  indeed! Say, for example, this case, my argument was valid, but if I phrase that in your way, it becomes (as you said, in your words) more **preferable** and easy to *comprehend* thus, making it *instantly acceptable* ! What do you think?...

Comment: I object to writing, e.g., $g(x/2)=1/2$ because your then have to define what you meant by $1/2$ in the context of the integers. There are, of course, groups in which some element $h$ satisfies $h+h=1$ so you have to point out that this does not hold in the integers. This ends up looking like what I wrote.

Comment: Thanks! @lulu, as I said before your argument is much *clearer* and *complete* in every sense. I do get it now!...